# Need to clean up log (SQL must delete all entries except the first each day)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I log speakers at different seminars by monitoring when they are going to speak. The table definition is below.

But during the last months, the database has grown in size and I don't really need to log every 5 minutes. Actually it would be enough to just log a speaker once every day for each room they appear in. So I would like to delete all the others. In the example below, Scott has two speaking sessions. One that starts at 1:33 in room 416 and the other starting at 5:00 in room 417, so I only need those two entries. The rest for Scott can be deleted. Matt has a speaking session starting at 1:42 and I would like to just keep that first entry and have the other 3 deleted.

Basically the things I want to keep is to select distinct days for each speakerNo, RoomName, SpeakerName. How do I go about creating an SQL to delete the rest? First I need to be able to select it, but I don't know how as I am fairly new to SQL.

```
ID  Time            SpeakerNo   RoomName    SpeakerName
409 2014-06-11 01:33    7646        416     Scott Olsen
410 2014-06-11 01:38    7646        416     Scott Olsen
410 2014-06-11 01:43    7646        416     Scott Olsen
410 2014-06-11 01:48    7646        416     Scott Olsen
411 2014-06-11 01:42    5140        210     Matt Jonson
411 2014-06-11 01:47    5140        210     Matt Jonson
411 2014-06-11 01:52    5140        210     Matt Jonson
411 2014-06-11 01:47    5140        210     Matt Jonson
412 2014-06-11 05:00    7646        417     Scott Olsen

CREATE TABLE [OnlineSpeakers]
(
   [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [Time] DATETIME NOT NULL,
   [SpeakerNo] INT NOT NULL,
   [RoomName] NVARCHAR(100),
   [SpeakerName] NVARCHAR(100)
);

ALTER TABLE [OnlineSpeakers] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_OnlineSpeakers] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UQ__OnlineSpeakers__000000000000000E] ON [OnlineSpeakers] ([ID] ASC);
```

Comment: Two points:  (1) You should tag your question with the database (which I assume is SQL Server).  (2) Your question probably does not do what you want it to.  If a speaker switches rooms and ends up back in the same room on the same day, you'll only have that speaker/room combination once.  If this is an issue, ask *another* question.  This question already has answers and it is rude to change a question substantially after it has been answered.

Comment: Thanks. That was a good point. Later I will test the two answers below and give feedback. They seem to do exactly as what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I like using CTEs and window functions for this purpose:

```
with todelete  as(
      select os.*, row_number() over (partition by cast(time as date), speakerno, roomname
                                      order by time) as seqnum
      from onlinespeakers
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Not all databases support these constructs.  But your syntax appears to be SQL Server which does.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Not all databases support" or "Note that not all databases support" instead?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt . . . I think I meant "Not" but typed "Note".  Interesting how that single letter inverted the meaning.  Usually, you need two or three letters for such inversions.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you the results that you actually want:

```
SELECT SpeakerNo, RoomName , TO_CHAR(Time , 'DD-MM-YYYY') SPEAK_DATE  ,
MIN(TIME) SPEAK_START_DATE_TIME
FROM OnlineSpeakers
GROUP BY SpeakerNo, RoomName,TO_CHAR(Time , 'DD-MM-YYYY') ;
```

For delete, you can probably try something like,

```
DELETE FROM OnlineSpeakers A LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SpeakerNo, RoomName , TO_CHAR(Time , 'DD-MM-YYYY') SPEAK_DATE  , 
    MIN(TIME) SPEAK_START_DATE_TIME
    FROM OnlineSpeakers
    GROUP BY SpeakerNo, RoomName,TO_CHAR(Time , 'DD-MM-YYYY')
) AS B
ON A.SPEAKERNO = B.SPEAKERNO AND A.ROOMNAME = B.ROOMNAME 
AND A.TIME = B.SPEAK_START_DATE_TIME;
```